# python Invalid literal for float

Tags: python

I am running a code to select chunks from a big file. I am getting some strange error that is

```
"Invalid literal for float(): E-135"
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Actually this is the statement that is giving me error

```
float (line_temp[line(line_temp)-1])
```

This statement produces error
line_temp is a string
'line' is any line in an open and file also a string.

Comment: kindly edit your question with the smallest possible code sample AND data sample that can reproduce the error

Comment: Yes. Its done. Kindly recheck.

Comment: so, what are `x` and `y`? are they strings? they cannot be because it would raise `TypeError`. Are they floats? then why do you convert them to float? It's not data sample that can reproduce the error.

Comment: float (line_temp[line(line_temp)-1]) This statement produces error
line_temp is a string
line is any line in file also a string.

Comment: may be you could just give us a couple of lines sample of your data and explain what is it you want to do exactly. I doubt anyone could parse your posts.

Comment: Thanks all i think the problem is solved thanks again

Answer (score 6):

You need a number in front of the E to make it a valid string representation of a float number

```
>>> float('1E-135')
1e-135
>>> float('E-135')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): E-135
```

In fact, which number is E-135 supposed to represent? `1x10^-135`?

Valid literal forms for floats are [here](http://python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/floating.html).

Comment: kindly check the question again

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to convert a string to a float.  If the string is `E-135`, then it is indeed an invalid value to be converted to a float. Perhaps you are chopping off a digit in the beginning of the string and it really ought to be something like `1E-135`?  That would be a valid float.

Comment: kindly check the question here

Comment: kindly check the question again

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you replace

```
float(x-y)
```

with

```
float(x) - float(y)
```

Comment: No actually i need that output in that form like 1e-35. it has to be this way or e-35.

Answer (score 1):

Ronald, kindly check the answers again. They are right.
What you are doing is: float(EXPRESSION), where the result of EXPRESSION is E-135. E-135 is not valid input into the float() function. I have no idea what the "line_temp[line(line_temp)-1]" does, but it returns incorrect data for the float() function.